# Energy anomolies in many body simulation

Tags: ode, simulation, conservation

I am trying to simulate the gravitational interaction between many bodies. I am using a direct PP force calculation and a 4th order symplectic integrator with a variable step size.

The energy of the simulation is calculated by this function:

```
real energy(body* system,int n){
  int i,k,j;
  real energy_var=0;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    energy_var += 0.5*system[i].mass*pow(mag(system[i].vel),2);
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
      if(i==j){continue;}
      real position_vect[3]={0,0,0};

      for(k=0;k<3;k++){
    position_vect[k] = system[i].pos[k] - system[j].pos[k];}

      real distance = mag(position_vect);

      energy_var += -Gravitational_constant*system[i].mass*system[j].mass/distance;
    }
  }
  return energy_var;}
```

In a test run with 100 bodies the energy( calculated every 100000's ) appears to be constant apart from one anomaly.

```
Energy = -3.23197e+41
Energy = -3.23197e+41
Energy = -3.23197e+41
Energy = -4.24807e+41
Energy = -3.23197e+41
Energy = -3.23197e+41
Energy = -3.23197e+41
Energy = -3.23197e+41
Energy = -3.23197e+41
Energy = -3.23197e+41
```

If it was a numerical or coding error i.e. the timestep being too high then I would not expect the energy to return to the same constant value. Is there a known phenomenon that might cause such an error?

Comment: If this was an inherent `anomaly` of the model, your code should still work for `normal` parameters. Start debugging your code with small examples that give results that are easy to interprete.

Comment: I have run the simulation for 3 bodies with stable circular orbits and the energy stays constant to 5dp for a long time. They also seem to orbit correctly from looking at the data.

Comment: Following on from @Jan, as you approach the anomaly take the energy and small time intervals and see if behaves in a physical way (e.g. smooth changes). How do you calculate the internal energy? Could this be error from numerical integration?

Comment: There is something wrong in your example... you declare energy_var as real, but the energy is $\approx 10^{41}$ which would cause an overflow of a 32 bit IEEE floating point variable...

Comment: real is a typdef from elsewhere in the program, in this run it is actually a `long double`.

Comment: Did you checked for underflow/oveflow conditions in energy computations? Not very likely with long double, but maybe its buried inside some subroutine.

Comment: A final thought. The energy will be infinity if the separation is zero. This is unlikely to be exactly zero but probably numbers close to zero could be causing the problem here? I think you need to isolate the iteration where the problem occurs and monitor that energy line closely.